# How to copy/paste image from Word to Google docs?

Tags: google-chrome, ms-word, google-docs

It sounds strange, but I am not able to copy any image from .doc or .docx to Google docs.

I have a situation when **I need to copy some into from Word document to google docs document** without uploading the whole word document into google. I can copy everything (text with styles and other stuff) until I pick image with it. Not only image doesn't appears in Google docs but it also breaks all styles in other texts (in copy/paste text of course). Not working with only picture copy/paste either (nothing happens). But, I can copy paste pictures from Google docs to docs (or simply copy paste image in internet) without a problem.

Can somebody please explain to me what kind of potential issue it can be and why its happening, or I simply doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the best way but just do "inspect element" on your image and open original image and copy from there

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately, inspecting element in Word document is pointless in my case, because I am selecting texts and images, and truing to copy/paste them to google docs document simultaneously.